# The system cannot find the path specified error when doing file related operations

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fptr;
    char path[150];
    char content[2000];
    char file[50];
    puts("Enter the path of the file");
    scanf("%s",path);
    fptr = fopen(path,"w");
    //fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\dell_latitude_3490\\Documents\\Hello.txt","w");
    if(fptr==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    fgets(content, sizeof(content), stdin);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", content);
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("Content Successfully added to File");
    return 0;
    
}
```

I don't get error when specifying:

fptr = fopen("C:\Users\dell_latitude_3490\Documents\Hello.txt","w");

But I get error when reading the path from user and specifying:

fptr = fopen(path,"w");

Someone help me resolve this...

Comment: Does the file definitely exist? Do you have the required permissions to read the file?

Comment: Change `printf("Error");` to `perror(path);`

Comment: Do basic debugging such as printing or examining `path` in a debugger.

Comment: I tried using perror(path), but it showed the same error - The system cannot find the path.